# How can i create a dictionary from a split string

Tags: python-2.7

I have a string data, i have to split the chars based on length and store it in a variable. How can i put them into a dictionary?

Eg:

```
str1 = "#161 fort street maddurMaddur       KAIN"
x1 = str1[0:23]
x2 = str1[23:36]
x3 = str1[36:38]
x4 = str1[38:40]
```

Comment: How should you final dictionary look like? you can do `str1.split()` you don't need to do `x1, x2, x3, x4`.

Comment: I used x1,x2,x3,x4 as they are split based on different length like 1-23 chars,24-36 chars,37-38 chars,38-40 chars. Finally the dictionary should be like {x1:#161 fort street maddur,x2:Maddur       ,x3:KA,x4:IN}

Comment: What you wrote isn't really a dictionary ...anyhow. What are you going to do, when the addresse changes? than you won't to use the same splits again right? If those are addresses it's better to check it with a `geo` api to get the addresse parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them into a dictionary like this:

```
str1 = "#161 fort street maddurMaddur       KAIN"
x1 = str1[0:23]
x2 = str1[23:36]
x3 = str1[36:38]
x4 = str1[38:40]

dict = {"x1":x1, "x2":x2, "x3":x3, "x3":x4}
```

Is `dict` what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with below solution, but i don't know how good it is.

I created a list as:

```
res = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
val = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
```

Then am creating a dictionary as below:

```
dic = {}
for x,y in zip(res,val):
   dic[x]=y
print dic
```